# Payumoney Codeigniter Integration

Tags: codeigniter, payment, payumoney

[image]I am working on CodeIgniter payUmoney integration. I have a registration form from where one registers and get paid with payUmoney payment gateway and form contains multiple select fields also. I need to use the payUmoney payment gateway.
So please help me that how can I insert the records into the database after the successful transaction in CodeIgniter.?

Actually here is my form. Now, what I want to submit the form but After successful payment. For me a little problem that where will I store the data till payment succeeded. Means I want to store the data after a successful transaction. One thing also there is multiple select drops down also, So please help me how to store the data into the database after a transaction using payUmoney.

Comment: I have done a CodeIgniter payumoney project. But i don't understand what is exactly your problem. Just change the transaction status from initiated to success after payumoney returns to your success method. Remember to check return hash verification to avoid potential hack.

Comment: Thanx james for your feedbaxk. But i am using test account. And I want to insert records after payment sucess then what the problem is when i fill the form and submit it redirects to test.payu.ib/_payment. But it shows error occured in payumoney page in payment page. And also pls tell me that how can i insert records after successfull transaction. I means if transaction is successful then can i insert records by just $this->input->post.. ? Pls help i m in trouble here.... Thnx

Comment: Are you getting checksum error or any other any other error? please specify. I believe that you have a transaction table to record all transactions with fields like transaction id, paid amount, status etc. After successful transaction update your status by using $this->input->post('status'); which is return by payumoney after verifying return hash. print_r($_REQUEST); on your success method will help you to identify all returns from payumoney.

Comment: Thanx for your response, actual problem is when it redirected to pau login page it shows an error.... Error occured nothing extra on the page

Comment: Can you post the error pageimage with your question for further analysis and please post the hidden form you are summiting.

Comment: Hello james sorry for late reply. Now the error is resolved but I added form image above. So please check description once and pls pls help me to resolve out.. Please suggest me a better way using codeigniter. Thanx

Comment: Happy to hear that you solved the errors in payumoney page. When we are submitting a form we also submit surl (Sucess url) and furl(Failure url) along with the form. When the transaction is successful payumoney return will return to your specified surl (Your Codeigniter Sucess method). A print_r($_REQUEST); statement will reveal all the return posts from payumoney. Now my question is did you really reached success page and is print_r statement works? If works why can you insert return values to a table ?

Comment: Hi james, I am confused with one thing. Actually I will let you understand the process what I am following. First I submit above form with all required fields and then post all the fields to another page like payu/checkout.php and store all the fields into hidden fields. but I there is an error with hash "Checksum error" while redirecting to payment gateway... Can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for your latest comment. The checksum error happens due to hash mismatch. after you submit the form to payu/checkout.php, checkout.php will submit a form to   https://test.payu.in/_payment (Test url).

Inside your payu/checkout.php

```
function checkout() {

        $MERCHANT_KEY = "enter your test merchant key here";
        $SALT = "enter your test salt here";

        $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);

        $udf1='';
        $udf2='';
        $udf3='';
        $udf4='';
        $udf5='';

        $hashstring = $MERCHANT_KEY . '|' . $txnid . '|' . $grandtotal . '|' . $productinfo . '|'. $fname . '|' . $email .'|'.$udf1.'|' .$udf2.'|' .$udf3.'|'.$udf4.'|'.$udf5.'||||||'. $SALT;

        $hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hashstring));
        $data['hash'] = $hash;

        //Loading checkout view
        $this->load->view('checkout.php');
}
```

In the checkout.php you must submit a form to   https://test.payu.in/_payment with all the fields I used in the hash generation except salt. The hash field is also in that form.

```
<form method="post" name="payuForm" action="https://test.payu.in/_payment">

        <input name="key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $mkey ?>" />
        <input name="txnid" type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $tid ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash ?>"/>

        <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $grandtotal; ?>" />

        <input name="productinfo" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pinfo;?>">

        <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa" size="64" />
        <input name="udf1" type="hidden" value="">
        <input name="udf2" type="hidden" value="">
        <input name="udf3" type="hidden" value="">
        <input name="udf4" type="hidden" value="">
        <input name="udf5" type="hidden" value="">

        <input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="hidden" value="<?php  echo $name; ?>"/>

        <input name="email" id="email"  type="hidden"  value='<?php echo $mailid;?>'>

        <input name="phone"   type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $phoneno; ?>">
        <input name="surl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base_url('payu/success'); ?>" size="64" />
        <input name="furl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base_url('payu/fail'); ?>" size="64" />
        <input name="curl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base_url('payu/cancel'); ?>" />

        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Click Here for Payment" class="btn btn-info btn-block" >
    </form>
```

For extra information remember to create a transaction table with fields like transaction id, amount, timestamp, status and all user's info fields. Before the transaction begins ie in payu/checkout function you need to insert this table with status initiated. After a successful transaction update status field of this transaction to success after checking return hash if you care about hacking( I check return hash because I hacked the payumoney site for testing and find out that if I don't check return hash my fake transaction will be successful. )

```
public function success()
{
    //print_r($_REQUEST);

    $status= $this->input->post('status');

    if($status =='success')
    {
        $txnid = $this->input->post('txnid');
        $amount = $this->input->post('amount');
        $productinfo = $this->input->post('productinfo');
        $firstname = $this->input->post('firstname');
        $hash = $this->input->post('hash');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $udf1 = $this->input->post('udf1');
        $udf2 = $this->input->post('udf2');
        $udf3 = $this->input->post('udf3');
        $udf4 = $this->input->post('udf4');
        $udf5 = $this->input->post('udf5');
        $key = $this->input->post('key');



        $SALT ="Your salt";


        If (isset($_POST["additionalCharges"])) 
        {
            $additionalCharges=$_POST["additionalCharges"];
            $retHashSeq = $additionalCharges.'|'.$SALT . '|' . $status . '|||||||||||' . $email . '|' . $firstname . '|' . $productinfo . '|' . $amount . '|' . $txnid . '|' . $key;
        }else{
            $retHashSeq = $SALT . '|' . $status . '|||||||||||' .$udf5.'|'.$udf4.'|'.$udf3.'|'.$udf2.'|'.$udf1.'|'. $email . '|' . $firstname . '|' . $productinfo . '|' . $amount . '|' . $txnid . '|' . $key;

        }

        $rethash = hash("sha512", $retHashSeq);


        if ($rethash != $hash)
        {
            $data['errmsg'] = " Invalid Transaction . Error Occured";
            //echo "Return Hash failed";
           redirect('payu/err',$data);
        }

       // now begin your custome code if a transaction is success 

    }
```

Comment: Yes James. Thanx for you support. I already done It and sending all the form control values from last form, But when payment is successful then I got only few values like firstname, amount, Email and phone. But I also have much values in the hidden fields.. What should I do.

Comment: Are you telling that your payment is successful then where you get the checksum error? ie if checksum error occurs how you make your payment success.

Comment: No I resolved that problem by myself with your continue support. But now I got the result success but could not able to get all post value from the hidden form. Should I pass all the fields into the hash or anything else??

Comment: Actually I am not able to get form control values like password, city of practice and some other fields.. What would be the exact solution to get all the fields? I am getting only values like firstname, email, contact number and product info and other payu credentials.

Comment: @PHPGeek payumoney will not return password or city of practice etc.You need to store this information before you begin a transaction. print_r($_REQUEST); will reveal you the parameters returned. For more information about the return parameters please visit page 7 and 8 of below document http://docdro.id/0UzhnFZ

Comment: So where should i store these values before transaction so that I can insert these records after successfull transaction.. I think it might not be a session.

Comment: @PHPGeek I edited the answer according to your need. Hope that it will help you to achieve your needs.

Comment: Thanx for you response. But I am confused that where I want to insert other fields also which are in registration form.

Comment: Then where should I store rest information such as passwords and countries... Means I need to insert those as well after payment successful.

Comment: @PHPGeek I think you like to post some more values like password and city of practice etc then store these information in udf1 to udf5 (user defined function). When transaction is successful payumoney will returns these values in udf1 to udf5 . Now for storing you can store these information before you submit your form to payumoney or after payumoey returns to your success page your choice.

Comment: Thank you James for your answer. But I already thought this idea, But Is it fine to send the password through udf and also return this in our success page.??

Comment: @PHPGeek yes it is safe. payumoney did not store your password or anything you send in udf. If you are concern you can store these informations before you begin a transaction.

Comment: And also one thing, should I pass these to hash string and If I pass them, Will it not show the error.

Comment: @PHPGeek yes else error will occur refer my code to see how to include udf along with hash.

Comment: I have included the fields values in udf1 to udf8 but it showing checksum error.

Comment: Yes done now. Thanx for your support... Thank you so much

Comment: Hi James. There is a problem when I use constant values in amount fname etc, then it works fine and redirect to payumoney gateway But while I use $this->input->post('') then is shows some error occured in redirection to payumoney? what the exact problem I am not getting the exact problem.. thnx

Comment: @PHPGeek can you post some codes of form along with your question for further analysis. The payumoney block form submission by ajax, curl and wget. Did you use any of these methods?

Comment: Hello@GeordyJames great work, But i am facing issue while checking the returned hash and old hash. $retHashSeq = $SALT . '|' . $status . '|||||||||||' . $email . '|' . $firstname . '|' . $productinfo . '|' . $amount . '|' . $txnid . '|' . $key;}
($rethash != $hash ) << both are not matching. What should i do?

Comment: and why we are not adding $udf1, $udf2 etc in the calculation of hash on success page?

Comment: @JaydeepGoswami  udf are user defined functions. They are used to pass additional information. It is an optional field and usually in all my cases it is just empty string.

Comment: @JaydeepGoswami you should add udf also in return hash calculation if that fields are not empty for you. Return hash is reverse order of transaction hash.

Comment: I did it in following way : `hashSequence = salt|status||||||udf5|udf4|udf3|udf2|udf1|email|firstname|productinfo|amount|txnid|key` This should help people in future needs